# My assigned TextView Intent Problem App Keeps Crashing

Tags: android, android-intent, textview

Whenever I run my app it works fine but as soon as I click the assigned Textview to intent to another Activity, my App Crashes.

```
Button backlogin;
TextView elecName, appointmentName;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin);

    // Initialize UI components
    backlogin = findViewById(R.id.backlogin);
    elecName = findViewById(R.id.elecName);
    appointmentName = findViewById(R.id.appointmentName); 
    backlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Create an intent to navigate back to the Login activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(AdminActivity.this, Login.class);
            startActivity(intent);

            // Finish the AdminActivity
            finish();

    elecName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Create an intent to navigate to RecycleViewActivity
            Intent intent = new Intent(AdminActivity.this, RecycleViewActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

    appointmentName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Create an intent to navigate to AppointmentFragment
            Intent intent = new Intent(AdminActivity.this, AppointmentFragment.class);
            startActivity(intent);
```

I don't really know what the problem is please help.

I tried putting clickTextView method but it has an error.

Comment: Post your error logcat and mention which one is your TextView for which your app is crashing.

Answer (score 0):

Verify whether you have correctly initialized the TextView and check the onCreate method in your destination activity for any potential issues. While identifying the problem might be challenging, share your crash logs as well it, would greatly facilitate the troubleshooting process, making it easier to pinpoint and resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If AppointmentFragment is a fragment, you cannot start fragments with Intent like activities. Can you try the code below?

```
 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
 FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
 fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
 fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new AppointmentFragment());
 fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
 fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: this helped me thank you now I know Fragment is different from a Activity